# How to display document.write in a specific div with specific id?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display my `document.write("something important");`

into a specific **div** with specific **id**.

Im my HTML, I have a div `<div class="col-lg-4" id="print"> ... </div>`

In my JavaScript, I have a loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < L; i++) {

  document.write(

    navigator.plugins[i].name +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].filename +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].description +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].version +
    "<br><hr><br>"
  );
}
```

What is the most efficient way to display them in my div ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend not using `document.write`, especially after the page has loaded. It can lead to unexpected results. Just use this method:

```
document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = "something important";
```

If, however, you did not want to replace the whole `innerHTML`, you could append something to it:

```
document.getElementById('print').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "something added");
```

**Update**

Here is an example with a loop:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('print'),
    L = navigator.plugins.length;

for(var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
  elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        navigator.plugins[i].name +
        " | " +
        navigator.plugins[i].filename +
        " | " +
        navigator.plugins[i].description +
        " | " +
        navigator.plugins[i].version +
        "<br><hr><br>"
  );
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Question for your first block of code, what if I have something more complex than a string. What if I have something like this : navigator.plugins[i].name +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].filename +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].description +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].version +
    "<br><hr><br>"

Comment: @iori If the variables you are using are declared, no problem, just replace `"something important"` with that. It's a String too, even if it's concatenated (put together). If it does not work, check your JS console for errors (F12 key).

Comment: Fair enough, let me try that.

Comment: It's works, but one more thing. I used more than 1 of this `document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = "";` so it override the old one, and I tried your second block of code, `.insertAdjacentHTML` , then it doesn't display at all. Can you show me how to append it without override the old one.

Answer (score 1):

man!
I think that what you want to do is update  the content of the element, right? If so:
`document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = something important`

I hope I have helped you